# Installer Developer VS a Software Packager?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm stumped on a job my Software Director needs to fill. I am looking for a Developer to create MSI installers using InstallShield. 
I keep seeing resumes of people who call themselves "Software Packagers" yet they say they wrote the Installers. If the manager sees the title "packager" he says no.

What's the difference?

Thanks for any help in explaining this! It's a learning curve.
Katie

Comment: 1. This seems more like it belongs on [programmers.se]; 2. Your manager is being dumb, he should be hiring based on the resume credentials and the interview, not pedantic semantical distinctions.

Answer (score 2):

A "packager" is typically someone who somes from an Enterprise IT background (SysAdmin) who has learned how to use a repackaging tool to create MSI's.  He might also have some experience in distribution tools such as SCCM and scripting using VBScript and PowerShell.  Maybe an MCSE also. This person tends to work in IT departments of non-tech companies.

A "developer" or "engineer"  ( or anyone who avoids the use of the word package/packager ) typically has more of a background in SCCM principals such as source control, build automation, release engineering and a more detailed understanding of installers.  They typically have a deeper understanding of InstallShield, Windows Installer, Windows Installer XML  and they might even have a developement background in C, C++, VB, C# or other languages.  This person tends to work for tech companies in a software development organization.

These are generalizations and may not fit all candidates.  I actually fit the latter but currently work for the former.  Take a deeper look at the resumes and see how the skills and experience match my description.

Otherwise, yes, I agree.  If they call themselves a 'packager'  I typically skip right past their resume.

Comment: Thanks! That does clarify this a lot. I'll edit one resume and resend it. The guy had hands on MSI Installer exp and C#. His title was Packager. You are all the best!

Comment: how their backgrounds in c/c++/C#,etc help in building an installers?

Comment: It tends to indicate at least a foundational understanding in the craft of creating software, how software works and the kinds of things to consider when coming up with or vetting installer requirements, integration and testing.  Also the ability to write well designed custom actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a person to create a MSI installation package for your software, then experienced "packager" seems right person to do this.

"Software packages" is very common conceptual used in Linux world, but for some reason not that common among windows users. `.MSI` is an installer package file format used by Windows.

MSI package usually contains files of your program + basically a database with a number of relationally linked tables. The Database contains information about what has to be done to the target Computer in order to install the Application. Shortly - where to extract packaged files and how to fulfil different dependancies so that the installed software can work.

Comment: FWIW, I dislike the word "package". It's overloaded and ambigous and has a negative connotation.  I typically will avoid using the word except when I must. In those cases I qualify the word such as "SCCM package".  I never call an installer a package.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I'd say there's some semantic subtlety involved here. A "distribution package" would be something that contains the payload of an installation, an "installer" would be software that deploys said package to a system. A `.msi` is both; a `.deb` on the other hand is only the former, the `dpkg` program performs its installation. Which is a fine point really, so it's understandable why someone would conflate those as long as the context makes it clear.

Comment: @millimoose - Can't we say that the situation is quite similar with `.deb` and `.msi`. One gets installed by `dpkg` and the other one by `Msiexec.exe` which is a component of Windows Installer and uses Msi.dll to read the package (.msi) files. When Windows Installer is installed on a computer, it changes the registered file type of .msi files so that if you double-click an .msi file, Msiexec.exe runs with that file.Each MSI package file contains a relational-type database that stores instructions and data required to install (and remove) the program across many installation scenarios.

Comment: @ErikKaju Ah, you just might be right. Just goes to show that pedanticism in this case is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: It's pretty well known. I've been doing installers for 16 years and every company that I've worked at for the last ten years has shared this view.